# ASP.NET MVC post a dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, drop-down-menu

When I post via the click on "btSave", in the controller I receive the model. In the model, I see the value off all fields (I show here only "FirstName" but there are others). But the doropdownlist value are null all the time.

Do you have an idea why ?

Thanks,

```
//Dropfown content
public class LkpTypeCompany
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int Code { get; set; }
    public virtual string NL { get; set; }
    public virtual string FR { get; set; }
    public virtual string Value { get; set; }
}

//Model Definition
public class CustomerModel
{
    public List<LkpTypeCompany> LkpTypeCompany { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

//Posting form
jQuery('#btGeneralSave').click(function (event) {
    var jqxhr = $.post("Controller/Actio,", $("form").serialize(),
    function (data) {
    });
});

//HTML
@model eSIT.GC.WebUI.Models.CustomerModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.FirstName, new { maxlength = 50 })
    @Html.DropDownListFor( m => m.Customer.LkpTypeCompany, new SelectList(Model.LkpTypeCompany, "Code", "FR", Model.Customer.LkpTypeCompany.Code))
    <input type="button" id="btSave" value="Save"/>
}
```

Comment: you can't use DropDownListFor on a Property of type List<SomeTYpe> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703436.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the overload that you were attempting to use but I have had good luch with using [`SelectListItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem.aspx)

Try

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor( m => m.Customer.LkpTypeCompany, 
     new SelectList(Model.LkpTypeCompany
                         .Select(i => new SelectListItem
                                      {
                                        Text = i.Code, 
                                        Value = (*somecondition*) ? i.FR : i.NL, 
                                        Selected = i.Code == Model.Customer.LkpTypeCompany.Code
                                      }));
```

Comment: I have some remarks : 1. I'd like avoid Linq or other C# code in cshml page; 2. I have an error on "SelectedListItem"; 3. it's not FR, it's may be FR or NL depending of the user language, the "FR" or "NL" text will be copy in "Value" field

Comment: @Kris-I it was a typo, it's actually `SelectListItem` and not `SelectedListItem`. I'm not sure how you can conditionally switch b/w FR and NL without linq. See my edit, and fill out the condition to determine if you want to use FR or NL.

Comment: Linq ok but no link in cshtml page. With your code in the dropdown I have this "<option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>" no value for the option. At this time I use "DropDownList" with a jquery post (get selected value with jQuery)

Comment: considering that the answer in for 8 years ago, is it still the best solution?